Hono abstracted routes with types
I'm trying to use Hono (4.6.12) with abstracted routes while keeping the types for the context / middleware.
For example at the server root we might have:
import hello from "./hello.ts"

type Env = {
  Variables: {
    db: typeof db,
    mqtt: typeof mqtt,
  }
}

const factory = createFactory<Env>({
  initApp: (app) => {
    app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
      ctx.set("db", db)
      ctx.set("mqtt", mqtt)
      await next()
    })
  },
})

export const app = factory.createApp()

app.route("hello", hello)

And then in another abstracted route file:
import app from "./index.ts"

// not valid of course, just wishing
const hello = new app()

app.get("hello", (c) => c.text("Hello world!")

export default hello

Anyone got any leads?
